# NavigationController Transition from transparent to non-transparent navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I'm currently trying to add a transition that is equivalent to current implementation in apps like Tripadvisor, Airbnb and co.
I'm talking about fading from a transparent navigation bar to a colored navigation bar and back.

So at first i implemented two methods.
`makeNavBarVisible` & `makeNavBarTransparent`
The implementation should be easy to understand.

```
public func makeNavBarTransparent() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}

public func makeNavBarVisible() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
}
```

This works like a charm.
Then I thought about the best way to animate the transition. So I looked into the **UIKit** Docs and found out that there is now one coordinator per transition that you can use for animation. So I configured the coordinator in viewDidLoad and it worked.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
          self.makeNavBarTransparent()
     })
}
```

Then I also added an animation block to the coordinator for the back transition.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
       self.makeNavBarVisible()
    })
}
```

And right now the problem arises for which I can't find a simple clean solution at the moment. When I use the interactive pop gestures, the transition looks correct. But if I press the Back button, the animation seems to be faulty. Why does the coordinator does it job when using the gesture but not when pressing the back button. This seems like a bug for me. Does anyone have the same problem as you and if so, how can you avoid it?

[image]